# How do i configure domain email account in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, google-domains

Like create email accounts in Cpanel is an easy job. How do I create email accounts in AWS? I have EC2 instance and my domain is on google. I wanted to create an email like info@domainname.com

Is SES service fulfill the requirement?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I think you need to look at the AWS service list and choose the service you need. SES is primarily for sending emails. Workmail is hosted email for business. Otherwise you can have an EC2 instance and do whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **[AWS Workmail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/)** - it can receive emails for your domain and you can access it through its web interface, Outlook, any IMAP client, etc.